# Definite integral of a function containing an exponential

Tags: integration

I have to calculate analytically this integral:
$$
{\rm J}\left(q\right)
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\rm d}x \over x^{q}\left({\rm e}^{kx}-1\right)}
$$
where $-1\le q\le N$
with:
$N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\le 5\times10^{-5}$
I didn't find anything on the Gradshteyn Ryzhik and Mathematica isn't able to integrate it. Is it possible to make some approximation because the little value of $k$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large{\rm J}\left(q\right)}
&=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\rm d}x \over x^{q}\left({\rm e}^{kx}-1\right)}
=
k^{q - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over x^{q}\pars{1 - \expo{-x}}}\,\dd x
=
k^{q - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over x^{q}}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\expo{-\ell x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=k^{q - 1}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-q}\expo{-\pars{\ell + 1}x}
\,\dd x
=k^{q - 1}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{\ell + 1}^{1 - q}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-q}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\color{#0000ff}{\large k^{q - 1}\zeta\pars{1 - q}\Gamma\pars{1 - q}}
\end{align}
The series converge when $1 - q > 1\quad\imp\quad \color{#0000ff}{\large q < 0 }$

Answer (score 1):

It isn't bounded for $q\ge 0$.

For $q<0$, it equals
$$ \zeta(1-q)\Gamma(1-q)k^q, $$
I believe.

Comment: $k^{q - 1}$ instead of $k^{q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica is perfectly capable of evaluating this:

ConditionalExpression[k^(-1 + q) Gamma[1 - q] PolyLog[1 - q, 1], 
 q < 0 && k > 0]

Since the integrate has an $x^{-q - 1}$ singularity at the origin, the integral diverges for $q \geq 0.$